# Angular 4 Force navigate with refresh

Tags: angular

In one of my component (which isn't the `AppComponent`).

I want for a specific call to navigate with a refresh of the whole app first :

```
this.router.navigate(['/en/homepage'])
```

I basically have an `APP_INITIALIZER`and some dynamic routing set in my `AppComponent`'s constructor and I would like that code to be run again before I navigate to my specified URL. So I am not looking for all my routerLink/router.navigate to refresh the app, just a specific one.

As I am using a server side app (with universal) I can't use `window.location.href`

Comment: Didn' test this, but maybe, as a workaround, can work:  this.router.navigate(['/?redirectUrl=/en/homepage']) then the root route will be called (and the AppComponent too) and there you can check for this query string parameter (subscribe to ActiveRoute's params) 'redirectUrl' and do a new navigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR;

You can simply use `location.href` (instead of `window.location.href` you mentionned)

```
location.href = 'http://example.com';
```

---

### More infos :

Location is defined in lib.dom of the Typescript SDK.

Here is the corresponding Typescript interface, which should hint at what you can do :

```
interface Location {
    hash: string;
    host: string;
    hostname: string;
    href: string;
    readonly origin: string;
    pathname: string;
    port: string;
    protocol: string;
    search: string;
    assign(url: string): void;
    reload(forcedReload?: boolean): void;
    replace(url: string): void;
    toString(): string;
}
```